# Retrieve DateTime locale offset using WINAPI

Tags: windows, datetime, winapi, timezone, locale

The Windows API provides [Time Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However I could not find a way to given a local DateTime retrieve it's offset from UTC, considering DayLight saving.

E.g: 2015 January 01 (Brasília Time) was on daylight saving period, so instead of -03:00 from UTC, the offset was -02:00. 
Now, today (August 02, 2015) we are not in daylight saving, so the offset is again -03:00.

Is there a function (or perhaps another way) to detect that?

Comment: I found a way but is a little bit off, subtract the UTC Date from the local date and capture the difference, but I would like to know if there is a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would you could do it is to use the [`TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function for this, since this considers DST.

Create two `SYSTEMTIME` structures for midnight on the two dates in question, convert them both to UTC, and then compare the resultant UTC times.

Comment: I think I understood your answer, but I wonder if you understood my question. The problem is, given a date, capture it's offset from UTC. My example was about daylight periods, not the dates I would like to compare. Substracting the dates does the trick but seems icky

Comment: Doing a conversion to UTC allows you to calculate the offset using simple subtraction. It doesn't seem that icky to me.

Comment: In my opinion is an unnecessary operation, windows probably has a way to do that without this math, it should publish this function.

Comment: What sort of a programmer is scared of math? :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I love it. However, I believe it is unnecessary in this case. Anyway, probably there isn't another way

Comment: If windows provided a function to capture the exact date of daylight start and finish. I would cache this entry in a key value where the year is the key and calculate the conversion to UTC in my application.

Comment: I think I could go with `EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation` or `GetTimeZoneInformationForYear` function

Comment: See my answer, isn't a cleaner approach?

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. Not sure your method is simpler though.

Answer (score 0):

For every given year, use `GetTimeZoneInformationForYear` and capture the start of both the standard date and daylight date. If the standard date is greater than january 1, consider the previous days as daylight time for the sake of the solution.
Use the member Bias and DayLightBias to detect the offset and how much you have to subtract in the daylight period. 
Give a date, detect the range of the date: 
Case matches the daylight period, the result is original Bias - DayLightBias (in minutes). 
Otherwise the result is Bias (in minutes).